# Youtube API Analytics Reports

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm using YouTube Analytics API to extract some channels information using something like:

```py
result = execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids="channel==" + channel_id,
    startDate='2023-11-01',
    endDate=today,
    metrics='views,likes,subscribersGained,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,shares',
    dimensions='day,creatorContentType',
    sort='day'
```

but I want to get reports from more than one channel and I can't figure out how to authorize more than one channel with oauth.

Authorization code:

```py
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"]
API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtubeAnalytics"
API_VERSION = "v2"
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret_2.json"
def get_service():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_local_server()
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)
```

Comment: can I see the code you are using for authorization?

Comment: @Linda Lawton I updated with the code